# How to read list if strings from one file and search in another file?

Tags: shell, text, grep

I am trying to read a list of strings from one file and compare it with first column of second file and print the whole line.

I tried `grep -f file1.txt file2.txt` but it compares the strings in the whole line and print it and I want to compare only with first column and print the line

Eg.

```
file1.txt

34534
67823
41400

file2.txt 

41400 41440 52705 10254 20239 39975 40075 71022 82531
43897 41420 71104 10252 20243 41400 71065 83830
34534 41440 83203 10266 20255 40086 70262 84476
78314 22540 60000 10250 20247 40083 82432
67823 41440 70000 10246 20231 39646 40092 71052 83531
```

output is:

```
41400 41440 52705 10254 20239 39975 40075 71022 82531
43897 41420 71104 10252 20243 <b>41400</b> 71065 83830
34534 41440 83203 10266 20255 40086 70262 84476
67823 41440 70000 10246 20231 39646 40092 71052 83531
```

Below is Expected output:

```
34534 41440 83203 10266 20255 40086 70262 84476
67823 41440 70000 10246 20231 39646 40092 71052 83531
41400 41440 52705 10254 20239 39975 40075 71022 82531
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use awk:

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{a[$0];next}($1 in a)' file1 file2
```

Output:

```
41400 41440 52705 10254 20239 39975 40075 71022 82531
34534 41440 83203 10266 20255 40086 70262 84476
67823 41440 70000 10246 20231 39646 40092 71052 83531
```

Explained:

```
$ awk '        # using awk
NR==FNR {      # process the first file
    a[$0]      # hash words to a array
    next       # move to proces next word if any left
}
($1 in a)      # if the first word of the second file record was hashed, output
' file1 file2
```

**Update**:

To print in the order of `file1.txt` use:

```
$ awk '
NR==FNR {
    a[$1]=a[$1] (a[$1]==""?"":RS) $0   # catenate records based on $1
    next
}
{
    print a[$0]
}' file2.txt <(tac file1.txt)
```

Above the order of records changing is demonstrated bu reversing the `file1.txt` using `rev`. Output in other order:

```
67823 41440 70000 10246 20231 39646 40092 71052 83531
34534 41440 83203 10266 20255 40086 70262 84476
41400 41440 52705 10254 20239 39975 40075 71022 82531
```

Comment: Thank you for prompt response, your solution also worked for me but I was expecting the output in the same sequence as they are defined in file1.txt. Is it possible with awk?

Comment: In the order of `file1.txt`? Yes, it is possible but requires either reading the whole of `file2.txt` into memory or processing it as many times as there are lines in `file2.txt` How many lines in `file1.txt` and `file2.txt`?

Comment: It still see the output in the order they are defined in file2.txt not file1.txt.

Comment: file1.txt has 650 lines and file2.txt has 3039 lines.

Comment: You are using the updated, the second, script? At least over here it produces your updated expected output.

Comment: Yes I used the updated script, here is the screen shot of the output https://imgur.com/zES6Ax0

Comment: Yeah, that `rev`.

Comment: I just tested with actual amount of data and noticed three issues, 1) It adds extra blank lines after some group of lines 2) It adds string 'NR' at the beginning of some of the lines 3) Some of the lines are merged in single line. Here is the screen shot https://imgur.com/gHVfV05

Comment: I see, there seems to be a "typo". I'll fix it in a sec.

Comment: Fixed. And it sure wasn't a typo, more like a brain fart. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

```
grep -f <(sed 's/^/^/' file1.txt) file2.txt
```

Comment: Thank you for providing the solution, it worked but is there any way I can keep the sequence of strings as they are defined in file1.txt?

Comment: Could you give me a concrete example of "Keeping a sequence of strings"?

Comment: I have just updated the expected output in my question, I meant the output should be in same order as it is defined in file1.txt.